# How can a User attribute be frozen after it is initially saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For my website, once a user selects his/her gender and saves the profile, I'd like the gender attribute to be frozen. This way a malicious user cannot go back and change his/her gender. How can I do that? Right now the User model has `attr_accessor` which includes `:gender`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify read-only attributes like this:

```
attr_readonly :gender
```

This will allow the gender attribute to be saved initially, but never updated.

Comment: Question: This means that I need to put :gender as both: attr_accessor and attr_readonly corrent?

Comment: Yes, you need to add both.